# Relay from postfix to exchange specific address

Tags: postfix, exchange

I have a very urgent issue where I need to relay some Emails to an exchange server.
Right now we have a postfix server which is taking all emails from @domain. We are using an external POP3 account.
What I have to achieve is the emails which are received in postfix to email@domain.com to be relayed to an exchange server in the same domain.
Right now sending works fine from exchange as the send connector is set up directly with the external POP3 account and not via the postfix server.
How can I achieve this? What do I need to change in postfix and how do I need to set up the receive connector in exchange?
What is happening now is the emails are sent from mail@domain.com to mail@domaain.local internally to postfix, which is fine for other addresses, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that i'm not familiar with postfix, but I found an article which introduces the method to **configure Postfix to Relay Mail to Local Exchange server** for your reference:
[Configuration example link](http://www.techspacekh.com/configuring-postfix-to-relay-mail-to-local-exchange-mail-server-in-rhel-centos-7/), hope it's helpful to you.